# Typeahead com acentuação

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead

Criei uma pequena aplicação que usa typeahead para fazer as buscas. Tenho cadastrado pessoas com nomes com acentuação e para busca-las eu preciso escrever o nome absoluto (com acento). Preciso que seja buscado uma pessoa com por exemplo o nome "felícia" sem precisar adicionar o acento no í.
o código que estou usando é o seguinte:

```js
$.getJSON("{{ route('getRamaisJson') }}", function(data) {
    var jsonData = data;
    var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
     datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('id', 'nome', 'ramal', 'imagem_link', 'funcao', 'departamento', 'email', 'aniversario'),
     queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
     local: jsonData
    });

    dataSource.initialize();

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
     minLength: 0,
     highlight: true
    }, {
     name: 'search-itens-list',
     // ao clicar em um resultado da busca o que vai ser adicionado no campo de pesquisa
     display: function(item){ return item.nome},
     source: dataSource.ttAdapter(),
     templates: {
      // se não houver resultados com base na busca exibir o seguinte template
      empty: ['<div class="empty">Nenhuma informação encontrada</div>'].join('\n'),
      suggestion: function (data) {

       feliz_niver = "";
       ramal = "";
       email = "";
       link = window.location.href + "/visualizar/" + data.id;

       if(data.ramal)
       {
        // formata o template dos itens que são exibidos na busca
        ramal = ' - <small><strong>Ramal:</strong> ' + data.ramal;
       }

       if(data.email)
       {
        // formata o template dos itens que são exibidos na busca
        email = '</small></p><p><strong>E-mail:</strong> ' + data.email;
       }

       if(data.aniversario)
       {
        // formata o template dos itens que são exibidos na busca
        feliz_niver = '<h5 style="color:#0273BD "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#318255" ></span> Feliz Aniversário!!!</h5>';
       }

       return '<ul><li><a href="' + link + '"<p><strong>Nome:</strong> ' + data.nome + ramal + email + '</p><p><strong>Departamento:</strong> ' + data.departamento + '</small></p>' + feliz_niver + '<img src="' + data.imagem_link + '" alt="' + data.nome + '"></li>';
      }
     }
    });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

biblioteca: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/